# mod rewrite redirect without changing query string

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect some specific URLs to another controller.
I have this rules in the .htaccess, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} diving/costa-rica-cr$
RewriteRule ^diving/costa-rica-cr$ new/url?id=29&landingact=11 [R,L]
```

What I'm not getting is redirecting without changins the URL that the user see in the browser (must be *diving/costa-rica-cr*). I tried with QSA and PT options but none worked.

Afted this rules I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} guias/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$
RewriteRule ^guias/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$ viajes/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} guias/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^guias/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$ viajes/$1-${countrymap:$2} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} viaje-a/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$
RewriteRule ^viaje-a/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$ viajes/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} viaje-a/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^viaje-a/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$ viajes/$1-${countrymap:$2} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} viajes-a-medida/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$
RewriteRule ^viajes-a-medida/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$ tours/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} viajes-a-medida/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^viajes-a-medida/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$ tours/$1-${countrymap:$2} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recomendaciones-viaje/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$
RewriteRule ^recomendaciones-viaje/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$ visados-y-vacunas/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recomendaciones-viaje/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^recomendaciones-viaje/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$ visados-y-vacunas/$1-${countrymap:$2} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (que-ver-en|como-es|idioma-moneda-horarios|vuelos|hoteles|alquiler-de-coches|fotos-de|viajar-con-ninos|tours|esqui)/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$
RewriteRule ^(que-ver-en|como-es|idioma-moneda-horarios|vuelos|hoteles|alquiler-de-coches|fotos-de|viajar-con-ninos|tours|esqui)/(.*)(\..*){2,}\.php$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(que-ver-en|como-es|idioma-moneda-horarios|vuelos|hoteles|alquiler-de-coches|fotos-de|viajar-con-ninos|tours|esqui)/(.*)\.(.*)\.php$ $1/$2-${countrymap:$3} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tools/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/.*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !fotos-tours/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (que-ver-en|como-es|idioma-moneda-horarios|vuelos|hoteles|alquiler-de-coches|fotos-de|viajar-con-ninos|tours|viajes|actividades|cuando-ir|visados-y-vacunas|esqui)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) public_html/blog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}donde-me-voy/vacaciones [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [L]
```

Maybe another one of there rules affect, but I think that putting the [L] flag finishes the rewriting right?

Answer (score 0):

The R flag means that the rewrite should be sent as a redirect, thus showing the new URL in the user's browser line. Just remove that. Neither QSA nor PT would be useful in your case, if that's all you need to do.

Comment: Hi, removing the R redirects to homepage (/).
I don't know if the fact that the first URL (diving/costa-rica-cr) doesn't exists as a file affects some way.

Comment: Do you have any other rewriterules than the ones you've posted? Or any AliasMatch?

Comment: I edited the question adding the other rules in the .htaccess